# Node.js Mongoose duplicate key when entering the same UserName

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

In my MongoDb database, the user-profile collection is following this schema :

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "566c69ab266ee48f24105a31"
},
"userid": "8d67e890-a0ff-11e5-9203-93a5a9af8b67",
"telnumber": {
    "value": "0600000000",
    "share": true
},
"fullname": {
    "value": "Oscar Götting",
    "share": true
},
"emailaddr": {
    "value": "x@y.fr",
    "share": true
},
"__v": 0
```

}

In order to reproduce this Schema in node.js, I am doing the following code :

```
 // Profile fields schema
var yokiProfileDataField = new mongoose.Schema({
  value: String,
  share: Boolean
},{ _id : false });

// Profile data schema
var yokiProfileDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, // User unique user-id
  emailaddr: { type: yokiProfileDataField },
  fullname: { type: yokiProfileDataField },
  telnumber: { type: yokiProfileDataField }
});
```

If I try to sign-up with a Name that someone else has already entered, I get a duplicate key error :

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: yoki_users.profiles.$fullname_1 dup key: { : { value: "Oscar Götting", share: true } }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/Rakso/Projets/Yoki/YokiWeb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/Users/Rakso/Projets/Yoki/YokiWeb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)
    at /Users/Rakso/Projets/Yoki/YokiWeb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:597:23
    at /Users/Rakso/Projets/Yoki/YokiWeb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:469:9
    at resultHandler (/Users/Rakso/Projets/Yoki/YokiWeb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:416:5)
...
```

How is this possible, and how can I solve this problem ?
Also in MongoLab, all the indexes's *unique* properties are set to `unique: true`, except those set to `unique: false` in my code, is it normal ? Could it be the problem ?

Comment: have you tried removing the indexes in question?

Comment: These indedexes are those which I am trying to insert, so yeah I tried removing them, adding them back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I flushed all the indexes and started with new ones. It solved my problem.